# How to get transparency into pcolormesh in JuliaLang?

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I'm using PyPlot on Julia.
I'm using pcolormesh and would like certain values to be transparent, so that you can see the pcolormesh plot that is behind.

In python you could do this with Masked arrays but, how can I accomplish it with Julia?

```
figure()
p = pcolormesh(XLAT[1,ind1:ind2],1:31,squeeze(Div[hora,:,1,ind1:ind2],(1,3)),vmin=min1,vmax=max1,shading="gouraud",cmap="Spectral")
p2 = pcolormesh(XLAT[1,ind1:ind2],1:31,a,vmin=0, vmax=2,shading="gouraud",cmap="YlOrBr")
draw()
```

p2 is an array with just values '2' and 'NaN'; and I would want that one of those values is transparent and the other has a color.

how would you do it?

Very thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, not the way i wanted but it worked setting all the 'out of range' values to a color, I didn't managed to reproduce the 'bad' values as I was thinking but it worked as NaNs get mapped to a value out of every range.

```
my_cmap=matplotlib[:cm][:get_cmap]("Spectral",100)
my_cmap[:set_bad](color="#663300", alpha=0)
my_cmap[:set_under](color="#663300", alpha=0)
plt[:register_cmap](name="my_cmap",cmap=my_cmap)
```

Cheers!